# Cakephp 3.x .htaccess issue on bluehost server.

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp-3.0

I want to setup cakephp 3.x solution inside WP website.

On my bluehost server, I have directory structure in `public_html` is as follows:
[image]

I want to access `stagetribescrm` directory and that directory contains Cakephp 3.x file structure.
.

Code Inside of `public_html/stagetribescrm/.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /stagetribescrm/
#   RewriteRule ^$ webroot/    [L]
#   RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Code Inside of `public_html/stagetribescrm/webroot/.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And the problem with this code is that it couldn't load css and js files inside `webroot` folder's file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for rewrite module is turn on or not in bluehost server than
follow below link:
http://www.abhinavsood.com/install-cakephp-in-subdirectory-of-wordpress/